# Why doesn't a TypeScript "Branded Type" differentiate in this case?

Tags: typescript

Conditional tests comparing indexed types using different branded strings doesn't seem to differentiate as I expect.

```
type Brand<K, T> = K & { __type: T };

type CatID = Brand<string,'cat'>;
type BirdID = Brand<string,'bird'>;

const x1: {[id:CatID]:string} extends {[id:BirdID]:boolean} ? true : false;
//    ^? const x1: true

const x2: {[id in CatID]:string} extends {[id in BirdID]:boolean} ? true : false;
//    ^? const x2: true

const x3: Record<CatID,string> extends Record<BirdID,boolean> ? true : false;
//    ^? const x3: true

const x4: CatID extends BirdID ? true : false;
//    ^? const x4: false
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgTgQwHYBMA8BpANFAKgPigF4oMoAyKAbygH1bRIAuPKAXwG4AoLx6AYQTAAkgBFisRKjQBnYHACWSAOZYA5AGMha-Nz6wFcFGInxk6OYpXqARoZQ7uXDQHskcqAA8AjCyoBtBRQmQRFRAF0mSyVlNigIT2AIVBlqQOCYezFImxcXABsIZDiAfih5AFdoFgAzBHyZCG4AemaodqgAPRKeV3dgLwAmP3SoJShQ7Kj5GLiEpJS0oLGkAyMp3IKipFLyuCqoWvrGlraO7t63D08AZhYAJQhXIzRJ0SxolUJ55JRUx+e6Ey63em0KyEIZUq1SgdQaTS4rQ6XR6ziuA08ABYWG94olfqlgcZxFD9jC4SdEWd2hcgA)

The indexes are different types (branded differently, at least), and even the values are different types (string vs. boolean).  Why would those first three `extends` conditionals return true?  As a final test, I checked if the branded types "extend" each other, and typescript reports that they do not.

Any insight here appreciated.  I'd like to be able to differentiate types by their index signature.

Comment: I don't think branded types are really supported very well in index signatures (up until 4.4 you couldn't even use such a type in an index signature). It might be an oversight. Looking at GH I found this related ticket with a bit more insight: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43852

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir - For this specific use case, `keyof TheObjectType extends CatID ? true : false` seems to work -- or am I missing something (as seems likely :-) )?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That works, I read the question more as to 'why' this works like this. But this workaround seems like a good answer..

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir - Yeah, the asking why is explicit in the question. I went back and forth on whether to post a comment or the answer below...

Comment: The explicit "why" is more of a rhetorical phrasing than a requirement.  Of course, it always helps to know how things work internally, so the "why" would be a valuable part of any answer.  Just having some solution is good too.  Thank you guys for the earnest replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak to the deep "why" you're looking for, but re:

> I'd like to be able to differentiate types by their index signature

...you can tell those types apart using `keyof TheObjectType extends CatID`:

```typescript
type Brand<K, T> = K & { __type: T };

type CatID = Brand<string, "cat">;
type BirdID = Brand<string, "bird">;

type Cats = {
    [id: CatID]: string;
};

type Birds = {
    [id: BirdID]: string;
};

type CatCheckAgainstCatID = keyof Cats extends CatID ? true : false;
//   ^? type CatCheckAgainstCatID = true

type CatCheckAgainstBirdId = keyof Cats extends BirdID ? true : false;
//   ^? type CatCheckAgainstBirdId = false

type BirdCheckAgainstCatID = keyof Birds extends CatID ? true : false;
//   ^? type BirdCheckAgainstCatID = false

type BirdCheckAgainstBirdID = keyof Birds extends BirdID ? true : false;
//   ^? type BirdCheckAgainstBirdID = true
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgTgQwHYBMA8BpANFAKgPigF4oMoAyKAbygH1bRIAuPKAXwG4AoLx6AYQTAAkgBFisRKjQBnYHACWSAOY4ARAGMha-Nz6wFcFGInxk6OYpXqARoZQ7uvcAKEyJVLlG9QA2gpQWQRFRAF0WSyVlbk4efRh7dxJPHz8AlgSjMXCoSJUYp31g-gALCA0AawBBZQQlOWCTEgqIEAB7ADMoYPcIAA9gCFR3RvEAfih5AFdoFg6EABsZCG4AelWfAD0JoqFS8ura+uBRiWmIOJduvbLKmrqkOUzjFAkW9q6eqH7B4YMs8aTOAzKBzRbLNYbbzbSZXYq3Q4PJ72YSvEjzJYXZyQf4ofZ3I6PE5CJpQd6dXG9AZDFAjEmA86gqAYiFcdZbHZXZ74xHHU7o8FY+L2Hn3Y7PUnkrrPKm-Wm4kw7YGzZmCyEc2E47kIsVEiXiEjnIA)

Beware, though, that a union can confuse the issue (as is often the case):

```typescript
type Chimera = Birds | Cats;

type X = keyof Chimera extends CatID ? true : false;
//   ^? type X = true
type Y = keyof Chimera extends BirdID ? true : false;
//   ^? type Y = true
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgTgQwHYBMA8BpANFAKgPigF4oMoAyKAbygH1bRIAuPKAXwG4AoLx6AYQTAAkgBFisRKjQBnYHACWSAOY4ARAGMha-Nz6wFcFGInxk6OYpXqARoZQ7uvcAKEyJVLlG9QA2gpQWQRFRAF0WSyVlbk4efRh7dxJPHz8AlgSjMXCoSJUYp31g-gALCA0AawBBZQQlOWCTEgqIEAB7ADMoYPcIAA9gCFR3RvEAfih5AFdoFg6EABsZCG4AelWfAD0JoqFS8ura+uBRiWmIOJduvbLKmrqkOUzjFAkW9q6eqH7B4YMs8aTOAzKBzRbLNYbbzbSZXYq3Q4PJ72YSvEjzJYXZyQf4ofZ3I6PE5CJpQd6dXG9AZDFAjEmA86gqAYiFcdZbHZXZ74xHHU7o8FY+L2Hn3Y7PUnkrrPKm-Wm4kw7YGzZmCyEc2E47kIsVEiXiEjnS440oKAC2EEQpkSUAAPtdgDJClcABpvVoU00Wq0-Gl0kJQJUgsGY9XQzk4t2G5XY6AATXdH26JXNloQ32pf31gaBwdVobZUKgMP0CejMy4QA)

Comment: Indeed, if I throw keyof in front of the types, that does start returning the expected result for extends.  Pretty weird that even though the _values_ are also different, TypeScript returns true for those extends examples I provided!  OK, onward with `keyof` for now!